# Count how many times a user clicked to a button in WordPress Part2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to count how many times a user clicked a specific button, for example:

```
<div class="download" data-id="<?php echo $postID; ?>"><a href="<?php the_field('download_url'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i> Download</a><?php the_field('download_count'); ?></div>
```

What´s best practice here? I think about to create a completely new database table and increment the value each time a user clicks on the button.

I am making two custom fields.
[dounload_url: url] [download_cnt: 0]

jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.download a').on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        var url_add = $(this).attr('href');
        var post_id = $('.download').attr('data-id');
        var ajaxurl = '';
    if(url_add && post_id) {
      $.ajax( {
        dataType: "url",
        url:ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
          'action': 'countDL',
          'urladd':url_add,
          'postid':post_id
        }
      } )
    .done(function(){
    // go to the link they clicked
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    })
    .fail(function(xhr){
    console.log(xhr);
    })
  }
}); // jQuery End
</script>
```

functions.php

```
function countDL() {
  $postid = $_POST['postid'];
  $file = $_POST['urladd'];
  $num = get_field('download_cnt', $postid, true);
  if(!$num){
  $num=0;
  }
  $num++;
  update_field('download_cnt', $num, $postid);
  }
  
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_countDL','countDL');
  add_action('wp_ajax_countDL','countDL');
```

Even if I click the link, the value of the custom field does not count up and I am in trouble.

Help me.

Comment: Your code seems ok to me. Can you confirm that you receive the id from `$_POST['postid']`?

Comment: Custom field [download_cnt] does not count up.

Comment: Is the description in functions.php wrong?

Comment: The `ajaxurl` is always empty string, and should be the the URL of your counter. On your counter function, you can optimize to increment directly inside of the db: `update YOUR_TABLE set download_cnt = download_cnt + 1 where ...`

Comment: Manuel Romeiro, could you give me some more advice?

Comment: Since you didn't share all code, I'm not sure about the problem, but only can help you you with clues. You have declared `var ajaxurl = '';` and don't change that value in any place. If the url of that action is the same where you are, that is fine. Also on `JQuery` script you are missing `})` at the end (opened braces: jQuery`(` function ($)`{` $('.download a').on`(` "click", function(event) `{`; Closed braces `}); // jQuery End`